# Laravel class autoloading for bundles

Tags: php, namespaces, bundle, laravel, autoloader

I'm having a bit of trouble with autoloader configuration for a bundle I'm writing.

I have the following classes:

- `Ravenly\Models\RavenUser` in **models/raven_user.php**
- `Ravenly\Ravenly` in **ravenly.php**

I am trying to do the following:

```
$exists = call_user_func($class.'::where_crsid', $crsid)->count() > 0;
```

But I get the following error:

```
call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Ravenly\Models\RavenUser' not found
```

I have tried setting `$class` (which is set in a config file) to `"Models\RavenUser"` as well, but I get the same error. I have my autoloader configured as follows:

```
Autoloader::namespaces(array(
    'Ravenly'           =>  Bundle::path('ravenly')
));
```

I don't understand why it's not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file name must match the class name. Your file should be named ravenuser.php

http://phpmaster.com/autoloading-and-the-psr-0-standard/

Comment: Ah thanks! I thought I was misunderstanding how `Autoloader` worked! I'm used to CakePHP's naming conventions...